# sql query extracting data with input from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

```
Customer table

customer_id|household_id|loyalty_member|gender|city|state|zip|phone_opt_in|email_opt_in|mail_opt_in
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Coupon Table    
offer_code_used|offer_desc|channel|camp_code|coup_start|coup_end|total
------------------------------------------------------------------

transaction table

customer_id|trans_id|offer_code_used|trans_date|trans_type|revenue
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Hello,

I have two tables with a common element (offer_code_used). The first thing I needed to do was to find how many coupons were redeemed in the month of decemeber, which I did with the following (the format in the date is a varchar with yyyymmdd):

```
select count(offer_code_used)
from coupon
where coupon_start_date >=20161201 and
      coupon_end_date <=20161231
```

I then want to know how many unique shoppers were there and the total sales revenue. For unique shoppers heres what I used :

```
select count(distinct customer_id)
from customer
```

Revenue:

```
select sum(revenue)
from customer
```

I finally would then like to know the redemption count by month for all of 2016 for a coupon that never expires (lets pretend that code is 'STACK') and how many of those were redeemed by loyalty members:

**P.Salmon suggested this query (I modified it slightly for use in postgresql),but I get a syntax error at the inner join line which I cannot seem to correct. I do not believe this solution is correct however what I need specifically is two columns; one containing the count of redemption of the stack coupon in a given month, and another column with the count of the loyalty members within that month that used the coupon. However this is definitely pointing in the right direction of how to solve this problem**

```
select T.offer_code_used,
         concat(substring(T.trans_date,1,4),substring(T.trans_date,5,2)) yyyymm,
         SUM(CASE WHEN C.LOYALTY_MEMBER = 'n' then 1 else 0 end) 'notloyal',
         SUM(CASE WHEN C.LOYALTY_MEMBER = 'y' then 1 else 0 end) 'loyal',
         count(*) as Total
from transaction T
where T.offer_code_used = 'STACK'
INNER JOIN customer C
ON (T.customer_id = C.customer_id)
group by T.offer_code_used, concat(substring(t.trans_date,1,4),substring(t.trans_date,5,2)) yyyymm
with rollup
```

This is where I am having a little trouble, this should not work and I am not sure how to check how many of those were redeemed by loyalty members. I know a join is involved on customer_id but I cannot seem to think of a way to make it happen.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What value in the customer.loyalty_member indicates a loyal customer?

Comment: Hello sorry for the slow reply, you were correct to assume the data types in the query you suggested!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem with the proposed solution is the position of your JOIN, conceptually, it is correct. The next query corrects for this mistake:

```
SELECT
    t.offer_code_used,
    substring(t.trans_date,1,6) AS yyyymm,
    SUM(CASE WHEN C.LOYALTY_MEMBER = 'n' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS notloyal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN C.LOYALTY_MEMBER = 'y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS loyal,
    count(*) as total
FROM
    trans t    /* I've named the table `trans` to avoid using a reserved word */
    JOIN customer c ON (c.customer_id = t.customer_id)
WHERE
    t.offer_code_used = 'STACK'
GROUP BY 
    t.offer_code_used,
    substring(t.trans_date,1,6)
```

You can check it on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b55bc/1/0). The answer you'd get is:

```
| offer_code_used | yyyymm | notloyal | loyal | total |
|-----------------|--------|----------|-------|-------|
|           STACK | 201612 |        0 |     1 |     1 |
|           STACK | 201701 |        1 |     1 |     2 |
```

---

Full definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
  customer_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  household_id INTEGER,
  loyalty_member CHARACTER(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n' /* ('n'|'y') representing a boolean */,
  gender character(1)  /* M | F */,
  city character varying(100),
  state character(2),
  zip character(10),
  phone_opt_in INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
  email_opt_in INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
  mail_opt_in  INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
  CHECK (loyalty_member in ('y', 'n'))
) ;

INSERT INTO 
  customer
  (customer_id, household_id, loyalty_member)
VALUES 
  (1, 1, 'y'),
  (2, 1, 'n'),
  (3, 1, 'y') ;

CREATE TABLE coupon 
(
  offer_code_user INTEGER NOT NULL,    
  offer_code_used CHARACTER(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  offer_desc CHARACTER VARYING(100),
  channel CHARACTER VARYING(100),
  camp_code CHARACTER VARYING(100),
  coup_start DATE,
  coup_end DATE,
  total INTEGER
) ;

INSERT INTO 
  coupon 
  (offer_code_user, offer_code_used, offer_desc)
VALUES
  (1, 'STACK', 'Stack offer'),
  (1, 'PROMO1', 'Promo offer') ;

CREATE TABLE trans
(
  customer_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES customer(customer_id),
  trans_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  offer_code_used CHARACTER(10) NOT NULL REFERENCES coupon(offer_code_used),
  trans_date CHARACTER(10) /* 'yyyymmdd' should actually be a DATE */,
  trans_type CHARACTER VARYING(100),
  revenue NUMERIC
) ;

INSERT INTO 
  trans 
  (customer_id, trans_id, offer_code_used, trans_date)
VALUES 
  (1, 1, 'STACK', '20170101'),
  (2, 2, 'STACK', '20170101'),
  (3, 3, 'STACK', '20161230') ;
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If I read you right the last sql statement in your question is the one you want help with. Try below query - note I have had to assume that the trans_date is varchar and loyalty_member is boolean

```
select T.offer_code_used,
         concat(substring(t.trans_date,1,4),substring(t.trans_date,5,2)) yyyymm,
         SUM(CASE WHEN C.LOYALTY_MEMBER = 0 then 1 else 0 end) 'notloayal',
         SUM(CASE WHEN C.LOYALTY_MEMBER = 1 then 1 else 0 end) 'loayal',
         count(*) 'Total'
from transaction T
JOIN CUSTOMER C on c.customer_id = t.customer_id
where T.offer_code_used = 'STACK'
group by T.offer_code_used, concat(substring(t.trans_date,1,4),substring(t.trans_date,5,2))
with rollup
```

Comment: should the where clause go before the join happens?

Comment: Actually this might be correct,  the substring is grouping by month which means we would only get 12 rows, and next to it a count of the loyalty but I also think it might be assigning loyal/not loyal to each entry